# How to create a spinner while url is looked up?

Tags: android, android-widget, spinner, android-webview, progressdialog

I would like the user to press a button.

When the onClickListener for the button is called, I would like to display a spinner until the webpage is fetched.

I don't want to use a AsyncTask because it can only be run once and more than likely the user will click the button more than once after the first url results are retreived.

So how would I go about doing this with this onClickListener?

```
findIT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        item = game.getText().toString();
        getUserPreference();
        itemLookup.loadUrl(url);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `AsyncTask<>`, you just have to create a new one each time.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new DoWhateverTask().execute();
}
```

Otherwise you can do it yourself using `Handler`s.  Assuming you already have `Handler`s defined for the UI and a worker thread:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    showProgress();
    workerThreadHandler.Post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            doNetworkStuff();  // Which will post progress to the UI thread if needed.
            mainThreadHandler.Post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    hideProgress();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Personally, I think AsyncTask is a nicer solution.

Comment: Also, just to add to the AsyncTask approach - the button can be disabled in the `onClick` method and re-enabled in the `onPostExecute` method of the AsyncTask in order to prevent triggering multiple AsyncTasks.

Comment: How do i go about enabling it?